# Why is a python float which was converted from a string not the same as a normal float of the same value?

Tags: python

I'm in Python 3.6.5 and I ran across a strange phenomenon: `float('50.0')` is not the same as `float(50.0)`, though they *are* equal to each other.

I ran some code to find the difference. Other than python saying that they aren't the same, I can't find a difference. I'm baffled. I'd love it if someone could explain what is happening here.

Here are my tests:

```
if float('50.0') is float(50.0):
    print("float('50.0') is float(50.0)")
else:
    print("float('50.0') is not float(50.0)")

if float('50.0') == float(50.0):
    print("float('50.0') == float(50.0)")
else:
    print("float('50.0') != float(50.0)")

if float('50.0') is 50.0:
    print("float('50.0') is 50.0")
else:
    print("float('50.0') is not 50.0")

if float(50.0) is 50.0:
    print('float(50.0) is 50.0')
else:
    print('float(50.0) is not 50.0')

if float(50.0) is float(50.0):
    print('float(50.0) is float(50.0)')
else:
    print('float(50.0) is not float(50.0)')

xstr_float = float('50.0')
norm_float = float(50.0)
print ('xstr_float: {0:.100f}'.format(xstr_float))
print ('xstr_float is of type:{}'.format(type(xstr_float)))
print ('norm_float: {0:.100f}'.format(norm_float))
print ('norm_float is of type:{}'.format(type(norm_float)))
```

and my results:

```
float('50.0') is not float(50.0)
float('50.0') == float(50.0)
float('50.0') is not 50.0
float(50.0) is 50.0
float(50.0) is float(50.0)
xstr_float: 50.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
xstr_float is of type:<class 'float'>
norm_float: 50.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
norm_float is of type:<class 'float'>
```

Based on some discussion in the comments I've tried the following, getting results that don't answer the question:

```
x = float(50.0)
y = float(50.0)
if x is y:
    print('x is y')
else:
    print('x is not y')

x=12345
y=12345
if x is y:
    print('x is y')
else:
    print('x is not y')
```

results in:

```
x is y
x is y
```

UPDATE: I've marked an answer that is correct, and based on a comment on that answer I want to show other people who might be confused what I was missing:

When python creates an object it is assigned an ID. `is` returns true when comparing two objects returns the same ID. Sometimes python will cache and reuse an object. So in the case of `x is y` we can see that an object is given and reused because the ID is the same. We also see that the ID changes between python sessions:

```
x=12345
y=12345
if x is y:
    print('x is y')
else:
    print('x is not y')
print('x_id: {}'.format(id(x)))
print('y_id: {}'.format(id(y)))
```

results in

```
x is y
x_id: 2476500365040
y_id: 2476500365040
```

and on the next run it results in

```
x is y
x_id: 2234418638576
y_id: 2234418638576
```

If for any reason the same object couldn't be reused to represent x and y then `x is y` would return false.

Comment: Don't compare values with `is`, use `==`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman it's obvious he is comparing value vs identity which is why both `is` and `==` are used

Comment: But why would he expect different objects to have the same identity?

Comment: Observe: `x=12345; y=12345; (x is y) == False` This has nothing to do with how the float is made.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm noticing that two different float objects can either be compared to be identical, or not identical and I'm trying to understand what the difference is. (e.g. `float('50.0') is not 50.0` vs `float(50.0) is 50.0`.)

Comment: @L3viathan I can't reproduce your results: `x=12345; y=12345; if x is y: print('x is y')` results in `x is y`

Comment: @jlsecrest Define them in seperate lines, not actually seperated by semicola; in a REPL

Comment: So to make this perfectly clear, you understand the difference between `==` and `is` and you're asking why CPython sometimes re-uses the same float instance and sometimes not?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I did understand that `is` and `==` were different but I wasn't quite clear on all the details. I did not understand enough of the mechanics of python to consider that a python object might be cached or reused. I've accepted an answer that helped me understand the difference more clearly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you might be confused with something that confused me as well in the beginning. `is` is different than `==`.

`is` will return `True` if two variables point to the same object.

`==` will return `True` if the variables point to objects that are equal.

The answer that helped me understand this is under this question:
[Is there a difference between `==` and `is` in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133024/8330337)

Comment: Ah. The question that you linked to does a great job of helping me understand. Thanks! So in these cases, it must be that python is "cach[ing] small integer objects, which is an implementation detail. For larger integers, this does not work:"

Comment: To add a bit to the understanding. `x is y` has the same meaning as `id(x) == id(y)`.

Comment: @user2653663 your comment was really helpful for rounding out the idea. I updated my question to show what you're getting at for those who have the same question.